# Less + Ago meaning

Tags: time, time-reference

Due to an argument with a friend, can you please share with your thoughts about the meaning of the next sentence? 
Could you please add an example with time period, i will really appreciate it:

> Write a query that retrieves all orders that their creation date is less than a month ago.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is a poorly written way to ask

> Write a query that retrieves all orders **whose** creation date was less than a month ago.

The task is to write a database action to find orders *placed*.

Suppose today is 10th August 2019. The search should produce a list of orders placed on 11th July 2019 and onwards.